# How to convert list into string without loop and join() in Python

Tags: python, string, list, sorting, type-conversion

I am given a task to sort list like shown below:

```
Input:  "Sorting1234"
Output: "ginortS1324"
```

without using **join()**, **for** or **while** anywhere in the code.
I succeeded after a lot of tries to sort in the required way, but I am unable to print it as a string

```
My Output is: ['g', 'i', 'n', 'o', 'r', 't', 'S', '1', '3', '2', '4']
```

Here is my algorithm to sort with sorted():

```
st=input()
def iseven(x):
if x.isdigit():
    return int(x)+9 if int(x)%2==0 else int(x)
res=sorted(st, key=lambda x: (x.isdigit(), x.isupper(), iseven(x), ord(x) ))
print(res)
```

Please help me on this

Comment: @borja, you pointed to a question less restrictive where all related answers are using `for` statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> but I am unable to print it as a string

Just unpack the arguments out of the list using the `*` operator when calling `print()` and use `""` as a [separator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print):

```
>>> L = ['g', 'i', 'n', 'o', 'r', 't', 'S', '1', '3', '2', '4']
>>> print(*L, sep="")
ginortS1324
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [reduce](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce), it is not in forbidden list. Append this line at the end of your code:

```
new_res=reduce( lambda x,y: x+y, res, "")
print(new_res)
```

Comment: The OP seems to be using python3, which doesn't have a *built-in* `reduce`.

Comment: 3.x still has reduce, just has been moved to functools

Answer (score 3):

Without using join, for or while:

```
print(reduce(lambda x,y:x+y, res, ''))
```

Implicitly uses a loop, but answers your question!

Answer (score 1):

Say

```
>>> L = ['g', 'i', 'n', 'o', 'r', 't', 'S', '1', '3', '2', '4']
```

To convert char list into string without `join` and explicit loops, you can use `array` module:

```
>>> from array import array
>>> array('c', L).tostring()
'ginortS1324'
```

or `struct` module:

```
>>> from struct import pack
>>> pack('s' * len(L), *L)
'ginortS1324'
```

To avoid `import`, you can use string formation:

```
>>> ('{}'*len(L)).format(*L)
'ginortS1324'
```

To avoid implicit loops, you can use recursion:

```
>>> def recjoin(array):
...     return array[0] if len(array) == 1 else array[0] + recjoin(array[1:])
...
>>> recursive_join(L)
'ginortS1324'
```

Comment: Please, add explanations to your code to improve your answer